# Bug with finding elements in a list with indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to find elements in a list called `boundNode` as follow:

```
[0, 4, 6, 7, 'x1', 12, 9, 'x2', 'x3', 16, 11, 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 19, 13, 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x10', 22, 14, 'x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 25, 15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]
```

I used a for loop to generate the indices like `4 7 8 11 12 13 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 29 30 31 32 33 34` to locate elements in `boundNode`

My loop is like:

```
   val=4
   ind=[]
    for i in range(1,7):
        for j in range(val,val+i):
            val = val+1
            ind.append(j)
            if(i < 6):
                boundNode.insert(j, 'x%d' % (j-(2*i+1)))    
            constraint_sty3 = str(boundNode[j+1]) + " + " + str(boundNode[j])
        val = j+3  
    print(boundNode)
```

I encountered a bug about `str(boundNode[j+1])`. It should give me elements on `j+1` location in `boundNode`. However, it fails to do so. To make it clarify, I can show you the print result of `str(boundNode[j])` and `str(boundNode[j+1])`:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 20 23 25 26 27 28
```

as you can see, it returns the elements on 4, 7, 8, 11......in boundNode

However, `print(boundNode[j+1], end = " ")`  returns:

```
12 16 16 19 19 19 22 22 22 22 25 25 25 25 25 23 25 26 27 28 28
```

It is not the elements on 5, 8, 9, 12......
I am wondering how to solve this bug.

Comment: What is your requirement and the issue that you are facing?
Could you please clarify it a bit more.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? there might be easier methods to accomplish

Comment: @nithin11 My requirement is to extract elements from `boundNode` based on the rule given above. The issue is that the extraction can work but encounters error when using `j+1` in a for loop about j.

Comment: @sai I'd like to extract elements from `[0, 4, 6, 7, 'x1', 12, 9, 'x2', 'x3', 16, 11, 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 19, 13, 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x10', 22, 14, 'x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 25, 15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]` to generate strings here.

Comment: You want to extract the alphanumeric elements like x1 from the boundNode list into a new list?

Comment: @nithin11 Not into a new list, but using these elements to generate strings based on some rules. For example, `x1 <= 4 + 6`.

Comment: I'm quite sure, that if you cleary point out, what's the input and the expected output, many answers with more elegant and readable solutions will pop up.

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo The input is a list: `[0, 4, 6, 7, 'x1', 12, 9, 'x2', 'x3', 16, 11, 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 19, 13, 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x10', 22, 14, 'x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 25, 15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]` and the expected output should be each elements on `4 7 8 11 12 13 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 29 30 31 32 33 34`-th position and the one next to them.

Comment: Now what are these positions that you have mentioned. Are those the indices of the alphanumeric element?

Comment: @nithin11 Yes, like `x1` is on the 4th in the list.

Comment: And what do you mean by the one next to them?

Comment: @nithin11 For example, The 5th element in boundNode which is `12`, and the next to 7th is the 8th element which is `x3`

Comment: So you want the alphanumeric element and also the element just after the alphanumeric element as the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225657/discussion-between-leyoung-chen-and-nithin11).